# Inserting a string at cursor position places it incorrectly when using a multi line text box

Tags: string, insert, textbox, multiline, cursor-position

I am creating a mini basic "emailer" using VBA. the user has the option to insert a "Name" field #name# at the click of a button at the cursor position in a multi line text box (Which is the email body). Once the user clicks send, the code replaces the #name# field with the Name associated with the corresponding address selected from a listbox.

Tab and enter are enabled for the text box.
The issue here is that it seems when the user presses the enter key, this is picked up by the Len() function as 3 characters? Eg.:

User enters:

A

B

C:|

Len() picks up string length as 9 chars here. So lets say the user wants to insert the name field just after ":" at the cursor position indicated above, it is placed as follows:

A

B

'#name#C:|

(Without the ') The cursor position is moved correctly though and stays after the ":"

Here is the code I am using (Got most of it from another source):

```
'Insert String at cursor
Sub InsertAtCursor(ControlName As String, InsertString As String)
Dim Ctrl As Object 'Object ref var
Dim strPrior As String 'This var records the string before the cursor
Dim strAfter As String 'This var records the string after the cursor
Dim lngLen As Integer 'Saves the length (number of chars) currently in the text box
Dim iSelStart As Integer 'Saves the current cursor position in the text box

    'Set Ctrl as ref to the MessageBody text box
    Set Ctrl = AdOp.Controls(ControlName)

    With Ctrl
        If .Enabled And Not .Locked Then                
            lngLen = Len(.Text)
            'SelStart can't cope with more than 32k characters.
            If lngLen <= 32767& - Len(InsertString) Then
                'Remember characters before cursor.
                iSelStart = .SelStart
                If iSelStart > 1 Then
                    'Saves all text left of cursor
                    strPrior = Left$(.Text, iSelStart)

                End If
                'Remember characters after selection.
                If iSelStart + .SelLength < lngLen Then
                    strAfter = Mid$(.Text, iSelStart + .SelLength + 1)
                End If
                'Assign prior characters, new string, and later ones.
                .Value = strPrior & InsertString & strAfter
                'Put the cursor back where it was, after the new string.
                .SelStart = iSelStart + Len(InsertString)
                'Return True on success
                'InsertAtCursor = True
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help here would be great please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue.
It is caused by the CR+LF end-of-line present in the control's content -> 2 characters. But .SelStart counts only one per line.
So, the full logic of this routine should be reviewed to workarround this.

Here is one that seems to work (should be improved and cleared) :
The idea is to work on a copy buffer with vbLf line delimiter (one char).

'Purpose:   Insert the characters at the cursor in the active control.
'Return:    True if characters were inserted.
'Arguments: strChars = the character(s) you want inserted at the cursor.
'           strErrMsg = string to append any error messages to.
'Note:      Control must have focus.
'Debugged:  WorkArround for Pointer issue on CR+LF (2 chars) as line delimiter
Public Function FormInsertAtCursor(Frm As UserForm, strChars As String, Optional strErrMsg As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim strPrior As String      'Text before the cursor.
    Dim strAfter As String      'Text after the cursor.
    Dim lngLen As Long          'Number of characters
    Dim iSelStart As Integer    'Where cursor is.

```
If strChars <> vbNullString Then
    With Frm.ActiveControl
        If .Enabled And Not .Locked Then

            Dim myText As String: myText = Replace(Frm.ActiveControl.Text, vbCr, "")
            lngLen = Len(myText)

            'SelStart can't cope with more than 32k characters.
            If lngLen <= 32767& - Len(strChars) Then

                iSelStart = .SelStart

                myText = Left(myText, iSelStart) & strChars & Mid(myText, iSelStart + 1)

                Frm.ActiveControl = myText

                .SelStart = iSelStart + Len(strChars)

                FormInsertAtCursor = True
                Frm.ActiveControl.SetFocus
            End If
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 438&, 2135&, 2144& 'Object doesn't support this property. Property is read-only. Wrong data type.
        strErrMsg = strErrMsg & "You cannot insert text here." & vbCrLf
    Case 2474&, 2185&       'No active control. Control doesn't have focus.
        strErrMsg = strErrMsg & "Cannot determine which control to insert the characters into." & vbCrLf
    Case Else
        strErrMsg = strErrMsg & "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function